# Convert javascript links in websites to regular HTML links?

Tags: browser, html, javascript, links

Some websites like to use javascript links instead of regular HTML links, making it impossible to open such links in new browser tabs, for example "javascript:OpenLink(908)", instead of "site.com/links/908".

Is there a way to re-write these sites on the go, using a FireFox plug-in, or a GreaseMonkey script?

Thanks!

Comment: You don´t know what the javascript will do when it responds to an onclick event, the new page might just be a generated html-element.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.

If they execute JavaScript, then they aren't strictly links. They cause browser to evaluate some code that does *something* and then requests browser to redirect you.

In theory you could make an extension that will:

1. Wait until page is loaded.
2. For every "JS link" pretend that it's clicked
3. Intercept redirection
4. Rewrite original "JS link" to a real link based on the target of redirection

There are some issues with this approach, though:

- As far as I know browser extension APIs (especially userscript API) won't let you intercept redirections
- Clicking links may have unwanted side effects on the page you're viewing, eg. it can disable some form buttons
- There is no easy way to distinguish "JS links" from links that are meant to do something on the website, but don't redirect you anywhere (typical for Single Page Apps)
- This procedure may partially depend on the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which, in general, is unsolvable.

There are extensions that do this for specific sites (for example [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) can "fix" links on Facebook), but there is no general approach that would work everywhere